# Why are a certain amount of images when using watir-webdriver but not when I use a regular browser?

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir-webdriver

So I'm using watir-webdriver to login to a site and download images using the following setup.

```
  def initialize
    @profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
    @profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2 # custom location
    download_directory = "#{Dir.pwd}"
    @profile['browser.download.dir'] = download_directory
    @profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "image/jpeg"
    @agent = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, profile: profile
  end
```

What I notice is that after logging in via watir, and then opening a tab and navigating to an image I want to download on a cdn server, I can only do this 3 times before I get a 403 forbidden session error in the browser opened by watir.  I don't hit this limit when I am using my browers and doing the same behavior manually.

1)  What could the browser and cdn be doing when I am opening it vs when watir is opening it that is causing this issue?

2)  Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like that site is sniffing the connection/headers/access-rate. I'd recommend a couple things:

1. Read their terms-of-service and documentation and see if they have an API you should use instead of scraping. If they have an API, USE IT! Scraping their pages can use more CPU and network time for them and that can irritate providers because it costs them extra money, causing them to ban you.
2. If they don't have those, contact them and ask if they have guidelines for scraping. It's possible they want you to throttle your requests to a certain number/minute or hour.

You want to work with them, using their authorized means of gaining access to their data first. If they don't have an API, then be VERY kind and throttle your scraping speed. Failing to do that opens the door to having your IP banned permanently.